# file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\project\test\portal\storage\framework/cache/...): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel

> file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\project\test\portal\storage\framework/cache/85/5f/855f92484c8c414d36c1b25cb24876e30229cbbf):
> Failed to open stream: Permission denied at
> C:\xampp\htdocs\project\test\portal\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:187

I am getting this error multiple times even though tried

```
php artisan view:cache   
php artisan config:cache
```

changed in the cache.php
deleted bootstrap cache file
I am stuck &I don't know what to do, Can any one help me?

Comment: you clearly have access problems... I know you are using windows, but if you are running something like WSL, you have go to the project root, and run `sudo chmod 777 storage -R`.

Comment: Thank you, I will start to download WSL try it.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have tried it I get the same error

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be because the following directories are missing:

- `storage/framework/cache`
- `storage/framework/views`

Creating these and setting appropriate permissions should resolve the issue.

Comment: First of all, did you create to different accounts ? Second, how did you not have this folders created ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti folder path is c:\xampp so its windows environment and I had  same situation before

Comment: @matiaslauriti and if it is linux probably permission issue.

Comment: I already have these files, Error shows in this file only @matiaslauriti, &Chinthaka Dilan

Comment: @ChinthakaDilan do not post as if you were the other user and fixed it... check your english please...

Comment: I have solved it, This was happening because of cache -Thankyou all